# How to edit, process and save an FTL file using java?

Tags: java, xml, freemarker

I have a code that parses through XML files, edits them and saves them (using dom for this). Now, I have a few files which have the **.ftl** extension. I have managed to process the ftl file with given answers (*using freemarker template configuration*) , However, I am unable to save the edited xml back as an FTL.

All of this is in Java. Any suggestions on how I can achieve the saving aspect of the problem?

**Again**, I want to process, edit and then save an FTL file in Java.

I am appending the code that I have for processing the ftl file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;

import freemarker.template.Configuration;
import freemarker.template.Template;
import freemarker.template.TemplateException;

public class FTLReader {
      public static void main(String[] args) {

            //Freemarker configuration object
            Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
            try {
                //Load template from source folder
                Template template = cfg.getTemplate(filename);

                // Build the data-model

                Map<String,Object> data = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

                //write code to get answers
                Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("src/answers.txt"));
                JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) obj; 
                data.put("element1", jsonObject.get("element1"));


                // Console output 
                Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
                template.process(data, out);
                out.flush();

                /*write code to edit and save the ftl file
                * 
                * 
                * 
                * 
                * */    

                // File output (the processed FTL file)
                Writer file = new FileWriter (new File("C:\\FTL_helloworld.txt"));
                template.process(data, file);
                file.flush();
                file.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TemplateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: We need to see some code. You can save the file by writing to an OutputStream of some type or other. But until we see what you've done, it's hard to suggest more specific solutions.

Comment: Alright. Added the code I have for processing the ftl file. Currently, as an output I get a processed FTL file. I am trying to edit this processed file (which is basically an XML) and save it back as an FTL file.

Comment: Also, want to add that the files I have to process are basically xml files with freemarker nodes

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Perhaps it helps if we clarify the terminology. Processing a template means generating output with the template, and the output will not have FTL construct in it anymore. Right? So what do you mean by "editing" the template? You edit is as what? As XML? FTL is not XML, but carefully written template can be. The output (of the processing) is possibly XML, which you can treat as any other XML then.

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguity in the question. I have an FTL file which is used to generate xml files. I process this FTL file to generate the corresponding XML file. After which I make some changes in the generated XML file. Once that is done, I want to change my FTL file such that if I process it again, the generated XML file should reflect the changes I made.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question and comments few times, I am probably finally getting to grasp what you are aiming to. So, you have to "patch" the file behind the `filename` variable from the start of your code (`Template template = cfg.getTemplate(filename);`). FTL file is basically a text file, so you can process it line by line. Then you must re-initialize your template with the new file content, i.e. do `template = cfg.getTemplate(filename);` again.